# how to filter out english records(including number and punctuation ) from records that include different languages

Tags: mysql

There are reviews that were written by peoples from different countries in different languages.
how to filter out just English reviews.

> I tried code like:

1. SELECT * from review where review REGEXP '^[0-9A-Za-z]';
2. SELECT *FROM review WHERE review REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]+';

> but still couldn't  cover all the result, especially the punctuation like (,;.''""&  ...)
>
> Excluded records:

- での疲れを癒してくれる;
- 好评,位置不错;
- מלון מעולה באווירה אוטנטית;
- Accueil  arrogant en arrivant le soir à;
- I’ve stayed at the Marriott last time during my stay in Hamburg and wanted to give the Renaissance a try. I surely was not disappointed. My titanium elite was recognized with an upgrade to a suite and free breakfast.

> expected result:

- I’ve stayed at the Marriott last time during my stay in Hamburg and
  wanted to give the Renaissance a try. I surely was not disappointed.
  My titanium elite was recognized with an upgrade to a suite and free
  breakfast.

Comment: How is structured your DB ?

Comment: And what's the purpose of your last sentence ? Are you advertising hostels ?

Comment: filter the col (varchar) that have different languages, just leave the English records

Comment: Unrelated, but you have a typo there, it should be `אותנטית` not `אוטנטית`